# Detect empty lines while reading from file

Tags: c

I'm working on a project that requires to work with files. I'm currently adding stuff to the file, but what I'm attempting to do is, when I detect a blank line, I will print something, and when the line contains something I will print something else. I was trying to store the blank line into a char, and compare it into `''` in a if statement, but I didn't have success.

Here is how my file looks, the 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 are not in my file, it's just to represent the lines:

```
1 Nilton
2 10
3 Ok
4 Ola
5 Oh
6 2
7
```

This was what I attempted:

```
char file_nome_receita[LOAD], file_ingredientes[MAX], file_modo_de_preparo[MAX], 
file_nome_criador[LOAD], newline;

int file_tempo_preparo, file_vezes_preparado;

if (file == NULL) {
    printf("Nao ha receitas no arquivo!\n");
} else {
    func_select = 0;

     fgets(file_nome_receita, LOAD, file);
    fscanf(file, "%d\n", &file_tempo_preparo);
    fgets(file_ingredientes, MAX, file);
    fgets(file_modo_de_preparo, MAX, file);
    fgets(file_nome_criador, LOAD, file);
    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file);
    sscanf(buf, "%d", &file_vezes_preparado);
    fscanf(file, "%c", &newline);
    if (newline == NULL)
    {
        printf("Bat");
    }

    fscanf(file, "%c", &newline);
    if (newline == '\n') {
        printf("result");
    }
```

Warning;

```
 warning: comparison between pointer and integer
 39 |         if (newline == NULL)
```

Comment: could you explain it better with a piece of my code plz

Comment: `fgets(file_nome_criador, MAX , file);` --> `fgets(file_nome_criador, LOAD , file);`  or better `fgets(file_nome_criador, sizeof file_nome_criador , file);`

Comment: `fscanf(file, "%c", newline);` --> `fscanf(file, "%c", &newline);` and save time (yours and ours)  by enabling all warnings.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I have attempted it, but my if comparison still wont print "Newline"

Comment: I count **seven** successive calls to read from the file with absolutely zero error checking.

Comment: Then don't consume the `' '` with the preceding `fscanf(file, "%d\n", &file_vezes_preparado);`  Tip: don't mix `fgets()` with `*scanf()`

Comment: @AndrewHenle What am i doing wrong in my if statement?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It was the \n from that scanf that gave me the erro, thank you, have a great day

Comment: It is good form to check fgets() return against NULL, like with error or eof.  It is also good to check the scanf() family return to make sure you got what you asked for.  The scanf() family also cross white space by default, which means it can go from line to line if the input is not well formed, so I am not a big fan.  In the scanf() family format, \n is just optional white space, The crux is to never trust your input!  Is line 7 new line terminated, or at eof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixed use of `fets()` and `fscanf()` created issues.

The below with `"%d"` consumes leading white spaces and then the text for an `int`.  No problem here.

```
fscanf(file, "%d\n", &file_vezes_preparado);
```

The `"\n"` consumes 0 or more white spaces and does not return until detecting non-white space.  This not only consumed the `'\n'` after the `int`, but also the leading `' '` of the next line.

---

Instead better to use `fgets()` throughout.

```
// fscanf(file, "%d\n", &file_vezes_preparado);
char buf[80];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file);
sscanf(buf, "%d", &file_vezes_preparado);
```

Robust code would also check the return value of functions.

Comment: So I should change this for my fscanf?

Comment: How about testing the return values of `fgets()` and `sscanf()` ?

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF Consider not using `fscanf(), scanf()` and use `fgets()` only for input.  It is more work, yet easier to detect errors and avoid problems like this.

Comment: @chqrlie As this answer has "Robust code would also check the return value of functions.", I am giving a nod to your [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62251454/detect-empty-lines-while-reading-from-file/62251921#comment110097966_62251921).  Yet there is much to fix here and this answer addresses a key problem.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I have inserted the fgets that you suggested, but, when I attempt to compare the newline with '\n' it wont work, but if I compare it to NULL, it will give me an warning but it will work.  The warning is comparison between pointer and integer

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF Post warning free code used to do the compare.

Comment: I have updated my question, so you can have a look, I had attempted to set the comparison to '\n' but It won't print nothing

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF Please do not change code once answers arrive.  Poor SO etiquette.  Consider a comment or append code.